# How to queue misfired jobs in Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to queue thousands of misfired jobs in quartz scheduler?

I want to avoid having all misfired jobs to fire all at once.

We're using quartz 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just limit the amount of concurrently executable jobs.

For example set the property [org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool.html) to 10 will cause that only 10 jobs could be executed in parallel. I.e. other jobs will be queued (depending on your [MisfireInstructions](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html)).